# Error while programing Spring AOP+Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-aop

I was reading the example available here: https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-aop-examples-advice , and I tried to implement an example, adapting the code to my previous project. I have a single web application that saves in a DB the name and the country of a given person, and I wanted to "intercept" the execution of the operations like updates or deletions.

I'm new into the whole Spring+Hibernate world so I don't know if I'm wrong with my code. So I'll leave you here some code examples:

My project structure:

> Package AOP
>
> - HijackAroundMethod.java
>
> Package Controller
>
> - PersonController.java
>
> Package DAO
>
> - PersonDAO.java
> - PersonDAOImpl.java
>
> Package Model
>
> - Person.java
>
> Package Service
>
> - PersonService.java
> - PersonServiceImpl.java

The advice method (as seen in the page mentioned before):

```
public class HijackAroundMethod implements MethodInterceptor{

    @Override
    public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {

        System.out.println("Method name: "+ invocation.getMethod().getName());
        System.out.println("Method arguments: " + Arrays.toString(invocation.getArguments()));
        System.out.println("Before executing operation");

        try{
            Object result = invocation.proceed();
            System.out.println("After executing method");
            return result;
        }catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
            System.out.println("Exception catched");
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

An example of my DAO class (here's where I implement the functions related with DB persistance):

```
@Repository
public class PersonDAOImpl extends HibernateDaoSupport implements PersonDAO {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PersonDAOImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Autowired
    public PersonDAOImpl(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        super.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void addPerson(Person p) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.persist(p);
        logger.info("Person saved successfully, Person Details="+p);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void updatePerson(Person p) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.update(p);
        logger.info("Person updated successfully, Person Details="+p);
    }
```

This is what I added to my servlet-content.xml (where I define the beans configuration):

```
<bean id="PersonDAOImpl" class="com.dacasals.raspertwo.dao.PersonDAOImpl"/>

<bean id="HijackAroundMethod" class="com.dacasals.raspertwo.aop.HijackAroundMethod"/>

<bean id="PersonDAOImplProxy" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="target" ref="PersonDAOImpl"/>
    <property name="interceptorNames">
        <list>
            <value>HijackAroundMethod</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

When I run this in my server (I'm using STS 3.8.1 with Tomcat 7), I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.dacasals.raspertwo.dao.PersonDAO] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 3: PersonDAOImpl,PersonDAOImplProxy,personDAOImpl
    org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveNotUnique(DependencyDescriptor.java:172)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1056)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:566)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1219)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1128)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1056)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:566)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1219)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:751)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:634)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:682)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:553)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I've been reading some questions here in stackoverflow, but I can't find any case similar to mine.

Comment: Are you autowiring the PersonDAO elsewhere in your code? The error methods leads to the point that you are autowiring the PersonDAO and dont tell spring which Implementation have to be used

Comment: please post your full spring-config , and recheck it. The issue is obvious : `expected single matching bean but found 3: PersonDAOImpl,PersonDAOImplProxy,personDAOImpl`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some misunderstaning with spring configuration

When you put the annotation `@Repository` on the class `PersonDAOImpl` spring, by using autoscanning, creates a bean called **personDAOImpl** and his bean implements the interface `PersonDAO`

Then you use the configuration file. Here you declare this:

```
<bean id="PersonDAOImpl" class="com.dacasals.raspertwo.dao.PersonDAOImpl"/>
```

In this case spring creates a new bean called **PersonDAOImpl** and this bean implements `PersonDAO` and it has a different name respect to the previous one (the first character is upper case)

Finally always in the configuration file you declare:

```
<bean id="PersonDAOImplProxy" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="target" ref="PersonDAOImpl"/>
    <property name="interceptorNames">
        <list>
            <value>HijackAroundMethod</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

This is a new "proxied bean" whose final class is `PersonDAOImpl` and this bean name is **PersonDAOImplProxy**. Also this bean implements `PersonDAO`

At this point you have three different beans all implementing the same interface. Beans are:

1. **personDAOImpl**
2. **PersonDAOImpl**
3. **PersonDAOImplProxy**

When you try to inject one bean in another bean by using `@Autowired` you can't simply use this syntax:

```
@Autowired
private PersonDAO myDao;
```

Spring doesn't know which one of the 3 beans should inject. So you must tell spring to use one of the 3. This is done by using the `@Qualifier` annotation. Let's suppose you want to inject the proxyed bean you should use something like this:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("PersonDAOImplProxy")
private PersonDAO myDao;
```

In this way spring knows that it must inject a bean implementing the interface `PersonDAO` and it knows that you want to use the proxyed bean

In anycase I think you would like to use just one of the beans so you should check your spring configuration and optimize it

I hope this is usefull

Angelo

Comment: Hi @Angelo Immediata, I took a look at what you told me. I removed some of the beans definitions at my servlet-context.xml and my application was able to run again, but when I try to access the form page I get an error. And the console doesn't show any explanation. I only left available the bean related to the AOP class, and the proxy bean, trying to run the AOP example but nothing happened.

I tried to add the annotation Qualifier to my PersonDAOImpl constructor but got an error too.

Comment: it's strange you have an error and no stacktrace on the console and/or log file. Try to check if yuo catch any exception and never print it

Answer (score 0):

Well, after some days I decided to try another way to use aspects on my application and now is working fine.

I read the book "Spring in action" 4th edition, and I found there good examples of aspects. Instead of using a "Hijack" class, I declared a new class using anotations such as @Pointcut, @After and @Before. Then, I was able to "listen" to the operations executed by my classes.

Although my goal is to create a generic way to "listen" events in 
Spring+Hibernate, this was a good start. Too bad I couldn't run the example provided by the web site I visited before. Thanks to everyone for your advices, soon I'll be asking again.